# rails cがフリーズする

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

現在、Docker上でruby:2.5.5-slim-stretchのイメージを使って、既存のRails5アプリの開発環境を構築しているのですが、`rails c`を実行した所、フリーズしてしまい、ctrl+cすら受け付けません。
また何度イメージを作り直しても同じ現象が発生し、コンソール上にログなどを吐かずにフリーズするだけなので、エラーの原因も特定出来ずに困っています。

どの様にすればこの問題を解決できるでしょうか？ご回答いただけると助かります。

以下に試した事を書かせていただきます。

「rails フリーズ」などで検索するとspringに関する記事が上がったので`DISABLE_SPRING=1 rails c`を試してみましたが、同じくフリーズしました。ただしCtrl+Cは受け付けました。
その際のログは以下の通りです。

```
DISABLE_SPRING=1 rails c

^CTraceback (most recent call last):
    36: from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
    35: from bin/rails:9:in `require'
    34: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    33: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
    32: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
    31: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    30: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    29: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    28: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:96:in `perform'
    27: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:15:in `require_application_and_environment!'
    26: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:15:in `require'
    25: from /home/hoge/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    24: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
    23: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
    22: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
    21: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
    20: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
    19: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    18: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
    17: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/config-1.7.2/lib/config.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    16: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/config-1.7.2/lib/config.rb:9:in `require'
    15: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/config-1.7.2/lib/config/validation/schema.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    14: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/config-1.7.2/lib/config/validation/schema.rb:1:in `require'
    13: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/dry-validation-0.13.3/lib/dry-validation.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    12: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/dry-validation-0.13.3/lib/dry-validation.rb:1:in `require'
    11: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/dry-validation-0.13.3/lib/dry/validation.rb:39:in `<top (required)>'
    10: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/dry-validation-0.13.3/lib/dry/validation.rb:39:in `require'
     9: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/dry-validation-0.13.3/lib/dry/validation/schema.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/dry-validation-0.13.3/lib/dry/validation/schema.rb:2:in `require'
     7: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/dry-types-0.14.1/lib/dry/types/constraints.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
     6: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/dry-types-0.14.1/lib/dry/types/constraints.rb:1:in `require'
     5: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/dry-logic-0.6.1/lib/dry/logic/rule_compiler.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     4: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/dry-logic-0.6.1/lib/dry/logic/rule_compiler.rb:3:in `require'
     3: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/dry-logic-0.6.1/lib/dry/logic/rule.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
     2: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/dry-logic-0.6.1/lib/dry/logic/rule.rb:4:in `require'
     1: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/dry-logic-0.6.1/lib/dry/logic/operations.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/dry-logic-0.6.1/lib/dry/logic/operations.rb:9:in `require': Interrupt
```

また`rails c`時のフリーズ状態で`ps aux`を実行した際の出力を書かせていただきます。

```
root         1  0.0  0.0  52060   188 pts/0    Ssl+ 17:01   0:00 irb
root         7  0.0  0.0  19948   224 pts/1    Ss   17:01   0:00 /bin/bash
root        15  0.0  0.0  19952   232 pts/2    Ss   17:02   0:00 /bin/bash
root        98  0.1  0.4  70268  9516 pts/1    Sl+  17:43   0:00 /usr/local/bin/ruby bin/rails c
root       101  0.2  0.6 344256 13292 pts/1    Sl   17:43   0:00 spring server | hoge | started 2 mins ago
root       104 18.2  1.6 420792 34064 ?        Rsl  17:43   0:30 spring app    | hoge | started 2 mins ago | development mode
root       117 12.6  0.5  71948 11292 pts/2    Rl   17:45   0:06 ruby /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring server --background
root       119 23.5  0.0  38380   360 pts/2    R+   17:46   0:00 ps aux
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

すみません、自己解決しました。
docker-composeが異常に重いのが原因でした。
お騒がせいたしました。